# Make website content editable for admins?

Tags: html, post, widget, blogs

I am newish to html but I have the capabilities to write a functional website for myself. The thing is, I update posts on it by editing the html code. That works fine for me except a friend of mine was wondering if I could make a website for his band. No one in the band has any html experience so I would like to make it so that it is easy for them to post on the website. Is there a way I could put in like a news feed type thing or a widget where they can post news in like a blog?

Comment: "Markdown" could be a good solution

Comment: @fred what do you mean "markdown"?

Comment: You can find more info here http://whatismarkdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

The term for what you're looking for is CMS, or Content Management System. There are a hojillion of these out there, and some of them even with free hosting. Here is a directory for php CMS:

http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=1&cat=CMS%20/%20Portals

[15 Best ASP.NET based Content Management Systems(CMS)](http://abundantcode.com/15-best-asp-net-based-content-management-systemscms/)

DotNetNuke is a popular Windows CMS. Here is a site with free DNN hosting:

http://www.dnn4free.com/